# How to disable animations in Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm working in a e2e test project with Protractor using Cucumber to test an Angular 4 web.

In the protractor config file, I have this configuration:

```
 onPrepare: function() {
    /* global angular: false, browser: false, jasmine: false */
    //Window size
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

// Disable animations so e2e tests run more quickly
    var disableNgAnimate = function() {
      angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(['$animate', 
      function($animate) 
      {
        $animate.enabled(false);
      }]);
    };

    browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);

    // Store the name of the browser that's currently being used.
    browser.getCapabilities().then(function(caps) {
      browser.params.browser = caps.get('browserName');
    });
   },
```

The problem is that when I execute my test, I have this error:

```
Error: Trying to load mock modules on an Angular v2+ app is not yet suported
```

I've used the same configuration to test an Angular 2 web and it worked fine.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in onPrepare:

```
// Disable animations so e2e tests run more quickly
    var disableNgAnimate = function() {
      angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(['$animate', function($animate) {
        $animate.enabled(false);
      }]);
    };

    browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);
```

Ref for more detail: [Disable annimation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/protractor-shared-conf.js)

Comment: Hi Dao,
Thank you very much for your response.
I've added this, but the problem is the error that i get:
Error: Trying to load mock modules on an Angular v2+ app is not yet suported

I'm testing an Angular 4 web.
In my old project, I tested Angular 2 and this solution worked fine for me